# Why this code is printing 0 to 297 but not 0 to anything greater than 297?

Tags: c++

As you can see, in this code , im just trying to print 0 to m . ive used exactly "m" as a variable.(ignone "n", the main thing is "m" here) if i input m = 5 ( accually i will type 4 to input "n" in my keyboard but ignore this , the "m" will be 5 ) .
so the code will print 0 1 2 3 4 5 . The problem i face is i can see 0 to m numbers perfectly only when m is 297 or less then 297. when i input m more than 297 , for example 500 . i can see numbers from 203 - 500 only . why i am not seeing 0 - 500?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  long n, m;


  cin >> n;
  m = n + 1;

  vector<long> v(0);

  for (long i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    v.push_back(i);
  }

  for (long j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
    cout << (v.at(j)) << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Looks like your console just doesn't save more than 298 lines to scroll up.

Comment: after you've run the program, scroll up, you'll see the rest of the numbers. There's nothing wrong with your code

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` Include the entire standard library. Not a good idea, and especially not when coupled with the next line. Good habit to get out of.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line. In `std::cout << (v.at(j))` the outer parentheses aren't needed, and using `at(j)` is paranoia: you know from the loop code that `j` won't be out of bounds, so don't waste time checking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This prints [0, 500] fine for me so it's probably a scrollback limitation. [Check the settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227744/terminal-limits-scrolling) on your terminal if you're using one.

If you're on a unix-like system you can use the `wc` command to count the number of lines printed and confirm this for yourself:

```
$ echo "500" | ./a.out | wc -l
501
```

You can also send the output to `less` which will let you scroll through it

```
$ echo "500" | ./a.out | less
```

Comment: This will also work on Windows - except the command is called `more`.

Comment: yeah :D ive figured out.. after Configuring CMD >> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491037.aspx

Comment: Gosh, I'd have just redirected the output to a file. <g>

Comment: @MartinBonner less is more ~

Answer (score 1):

Because you have configured your terminal to show only the most recent 298 lines.

Configure it to show more of what is known as "scrollback".